# How to fix 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, efficientnet

I am using layer from efficientnet for some postprocessing on that layer but after extracting the layer and performing the operation on that it shows that :

> **AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer' .**

Running on `python 3.6.2` with `tensorflow 2.0` an `keras 2.2.4`. Tried with the keras model like ResNet and its working fine.

```
base_model = EfficientNetB4((img_height, img_width, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
base_model.summary()    
x = base_model.get_layer('swish_96').output
x_a = ASPP(x)
```

**ASPP**(atrous spatial pyramid pooling) is class performing various layer operation on x after getting the layer.

Comment: Please include full code that reproduces the problem and full traceback

Answer (score 1):

Version conflict of tensorflow and keras. Solved by changing it to tf 1.14.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not all TensorFlow 2.0 packages support Python 3.7

this worked for me

`conda create -y --name tensorflow python=3.6`

type in this before entering the environment

```
conda activate tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem like this, building a model with the same error.
Fix it by making sure layers all come from tf.keras( maybe keras is ok too)

That is :

input layers and output layers are all built from tf.keras